# How to use Vulkan images concurrently on different queues

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, vulkan

The is a primarily architectural / conceptual question.  In my current project I have a compute queue and a graphics queue, which sometimes are the same but for many devices are different.  I have a somewhat sophisticated dependency chain for a `VkImage`. I have a thread for compute commands which run at a fixed time step, and then a graphics thread for drawing commands without a fixed time step.  The compute thread dispatches a writes image command, which is then used by another compute dispatch later on.  The image is also used in drawing.  The following text below summarizes the relationship.

```
Compute Thread -> Fixed Time Step + Fence -> Dispatch Write to Image -> Later Dispatch Computation use Image Sampler

Graphics Thread -> Swapchain and Fence -> Draw and use Image Sampler
```

Both the later dispatch and draw use `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL`.  Since both of these threads are running concurrently, I presume there would be an error if a render call occurs at the same time as the image write dispatch, since the image will be in a different layout.

What is the correct way to manage concurrent, different layout usages, of a VkImage? Do I need to have 2 `VkImage`s and transfer the image to the graphics queue, after the first dispatch?  And if so, should I use a memory barrier on the dst image in the graphics queue?

I read through some of these synchronization examples: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/wiki/Synchronization-Examples, and nothing immediately jumped out at me for my use case.

Comment: Could you please be more precise in your problem formulation? Is it like you want to operate on data with one thread and draw that data on the other thread simultaneously? If yes, then try reading about double-buffering.

Comment: One thread generates data consumes it ,and another thread draws with it.  I already have a swapchain setup.  My question has to do with how vulkan handles concurrent usages of an image resource.  I will try to make the question clearer

Comment: Just a wild-ass guess that you may want to read this: https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Texture_mapping/Images